# Check if value exists in a comma separated list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following values in my sql column:-

```
a,b,c,d e,f
```

I want to check if `b` is present in the column.

Comment: You've tagged this with MySQL, but there's absolutely no point in using an RDBMS for comma-separated data.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
FIND_IN_SET('b',yourcolumn) > 0
```

As an example to be used in a query:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE FIND_IN_SET('b',yourcolumn) > 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use FIND_IN_SET()

```
FIND_IN_SET('a','a,b,c,d,e');
```

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use a like clause on the column, for eg, if the column name contains these values in the users table you can use this query

```
select * from users where name like "%b%";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from users where name like "%,b,%" OR name like "b,%" OR name like "%,b" ;
```